# Допустимо ли подобное тире?

Tags: пунктуация

В 2013 году количество экспонентов составило 1482 – из них зарубежных 676 из 28 стран, а количество посетителей составило 71 447 человек из 55 стран.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я поставил бы перед "из них зарубежных..." запятую, так как здесь присоединительный оборот. Ср.: "...количество экспонетов составило 1482, в том числе зарубежных..."